# NSLocalizedString seems to ignore regions unless there is nothing else. Is this true or am i doing something wrong?

Tags: iphone, nslocalizedstring, localized

For my localizable strings I currently have an en, fr and en_CA.  It all works fine and well except when I'm trying to use the en_CA.  I have it set right and it is even reporting the currentLocale is en_CA but it still seems to use the en's values instead of the en_CA's.  Has anyone faced this before?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Locales are not localizations.

- NSLocale correspond to the "Region Format" setting.
- Bundle localizations correspond to the "Language" setting.

There is no "Canadian English" language (only "English", and in 4.0 "British English").